# Multiply results of two different functions

Tags: php

I have placed results of two functions in two different columns of a table.  In the third column I want to multiply the two results.  Multiplication shows zero.  First result is 6 and second is 3 - addition shows 63 (like string addition).

```
<tr>
    <td>Economics</td><td><?php echo $e; ?></td><!--Economics marks-->
    <td><?php $gra = sg($e);  ?></td><!--Economics grade using function sg()-->
    <td><?php $grap = sgp($e); ?></td><!--Economics grade points using sgp() function.-->
    <td><?php echo $ec; ?></td><!--Economics credits-->
    <td><?php $ce = ce3($e); ?></td><!--Economics credits earned using function ce3()-->
    <td><?php echo $ce * $grap;  ?></td><!--multiplication of two function results - this should be 18 - 3 x 6 but shows 3.-->
</tr>
```

Function to calculate earned credits:-

```
function ce3($marks) {
    if ($marks == "A" || $marks == "CC") {
        $marks = "---";
        echo $marks;
    } else {
        $marks = 3;
        echo $marks;
    }
}
```

Function to calculate grade points:-

```
function sgp ($marks) {

    if ($marks == "A" || $marks =="CC") {
        $marks = "---";
        echo $marks;
    } elseif ($marks < 40) {
        $marks = 0;
        echo $marks;
    } elseif ($marks >= 40 && $marks < 45) {
        $marks = 4;
        echo $marks;
    } elseif ($marks >= 45 && $marks < 50) {
        $marks = 5;
        echo $marks;
    } elseif ($marks >= 50 && $marks < 55) {
        $marks = 6;
        echo $marks;
    } elseif ($marks >= 55 && $marks < 60) {
        $marks = 7;
        echo $marks;
    } elseif ($marks >= 60 && $marks < 70) {
        $marks = 8;
        echo $marks;
    } elseif ($marks >= 70 && $marks < 80) {
        $marks = 9;
        echo $marks;
    } elseif ($marks >= 80) {
        $marks = 10;
        echo $marks;
    }
}
```

Comment: whats your `$e` value?

Comment: Either marks ranging from 0 to 100 or A for absent and CC for copy case

Comment: as Ashwyn Horton answered below you are missing `return` satements in your both function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing return statements in your function...

```
function ce3($marks) {
    if ($marks == "A" || $marks == "CC") {
        $marks = "---";
        echo $marks;
    }
    else {$marks = 3;
        echo $marks;
    }
    return $marks;
}
```

your `sgp()` function also.